# How to make fold perform multiple folds based on a category

Tags: haskell, fold

What operator can I pass to one of the fold variants that will allow me to sum tuple item 2 grouped by tuple item 1, in a list of tuples?

So, let's say I have the list:

```
[ ('A', 1) , ('A', 3) , ('B', 4 ) , ('C', 10) , ('C', 1) ]
```

and I want to produce the list:

```
[ ('A', 4) , ('B', 4) , ('C', 11) ]
```

You can see it's a Haskell-ized table, and so the actual representation of the table here isn't important; it's the approach to taking the input data and producing the output I am interested in. I am a Haskell newcomer, and have a background in C/C++/C#. I've done enough tutorials to recognise the application of fold here, but can't figure out the sub-folding that appears to be required.

EDIT:
In case this helps anyone else, here is my solution using group, foldl1 and map, inspired by ingo's response:

```
import qualified Data.List as List

mygroup :: [ (Char,Int) ] -> [ [(Char,Int)] ]
mygroup = List.groupBy (\x y -> fst x == fst y) 

myfold :: [(Char,Int)] -> (Char,Int)
myfold = foldl1 (\x y -> (fst x, snd x + snd y))

mysum :: [(Char,Int)] -> [(Char,Int)]
mysum = map myfold . mygroup
```

When run:

```
*ListSum> mysum [ ('A',1) , ('A',2) , ('B',3) , ('C',4) , ('C',5) ]
[('A',3),('B',3),('C',9)]
```

**mygroup** shows how to create groups, by providing an equivalence operator. It says that two members are in the same group if their first tuple items are the same.

**myfold** shows how to sum two tuples. It uses the first tuple in the list as the initial state for the fold, and composes a result tuple from the the sum of each tuple's second items.

**mysum** composes these two functions using map.

I might spend a bit more time on this to see if I can break the dependence on the schema of the data, which is currently **[(Char,Int)]**. I think it means supplying the groupBy operator and the fold operator, and might just be an exercise in composing the groupBy, foldl1 and map. I'm new at this.

Do I get any points for being point-free? :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Folds are sort of the "goto" of functional programming: dang useful for certain things, but mainly there as a stepping-stone for higher-level stuff (like [`groupBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) and [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:map)).

Comment: @dbaupp: No. I can't see how to write the fold operator to perform the subfolds.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Thank you, that advice nicely supports shang's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is really about grouping items with a specific criteria and then folding over the groups.

The simplest way to implement the example you gave is to use an associative map from `Data.Map` to group the items.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

sumGroups :: [(Char, Int)] -> [(Char, Int)]
sumGroups = Map.assocs . Map.fromListWith (+)
```

This uses the function [`fromListWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v%3afromListWith) to combine items which have the same key, and the resulting map is converted back into a list with [`assocs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v%3aassocs).

```
*Main> sumGroups [ ('A', 1) , ('A', 3) , ('B', 4 ) , ('C', 10) , ('C', 1) ]
[('A',4),('B',4),('C',11)]
```

Comment: OK, that is beautiful. I am kind of relieved to see the need for a grouping operation there, because that's what my instincts told me; however I was sure that was my reptilian imperative analysis of the problem, and I needed to know how you Haskeller's did it. I now want to modify this for multiple keys, but I think I know how to do this with what you've given me here. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Pointless fun:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function
import Control.Arrow

sumGroups = map (fst . head &&& sum . map snd) . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
```

Comment: Researching this response led me to "arrows" and "robots" (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows). Very interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need two steps, conceptually:

```
transform [('A', 1) , ('A', 3) , ('B', 4 ) , ('C', 10) , ('C', 1)]
to [('A', [1,3,4]), ('C', [10, 1])]
and further to [('A', 8), ('C', 11)]
```

Functions that will help you: groupBy, using, fst, map, sum

Comment: An answer in lego-kit form; I'll take that, since it gives me some keywords to research; thank you. I would say that the the first transformation is the one that puzzles me, since I know that mapping fold to the transformed list is all I need from there. However, groupBy looks very interesting.